# C++ IDE supporting header file refactoring

Tags: c++, ide, refactoring

Background: 
I'm coming from a Java background and am new to C++.  I've played around in Visual C++ and Eclipse CDT.

Question:
What are some free (cost-wise) IDE/plugin combos you recommend that support header file refactoring?  I change class names all the time in Java and this would seem like a nightmare in C++ without refactoring.

Comment: This question will be closed, however I recommend QtCreator (Cross-platform), or KDevelop (mostly *nix only), you can use QtCreator to create c++ projects without depending on Qt, it's a very good IDE.

Comment: Why will it be closed?  I didn't find this answer in other threads.  So much help this site is heh.

Comment: It's opinion based I think, people here are uptight about that kinda things.

Comment: The reason is: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: There ya go, politics are slowly sucking the life of this site, like everything else in life.

Comment: I'm not asking for opinions or recommendations.  Just an objective list of IDEs/plugin combos that support refactoring.  But I see your guys' points.

Comment: The close reason offered suffers from itself being an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [QtCreator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/index.html), it has some very good refactoring support, supports CMake, C++11 and works on *nix/Windows.

[KDevelop](http://kdevelop.org/) is also very good.

Comment: But how do I refactor header files in QTCreator, i.e. if I rename abc.h to xyz.h, I want all of my #includes to reflect the name change?